# Match all line-breaks inside tags

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have something like that:

```
sometext
<blockquote>Posted by user on date:<br />The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</blockquote>
sometext
```

I want to match all line-breaks (so, all `<br />` here) to replace them, only if they are in a `blockquote` element. The goal being converting to something like this:

```
sometext
> Posted by user on date:
> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
sometext
```

I've been stuggling to make a single regex to catch only all the `<br />` inside `<blockquote>` elements. I guess I should use the lookarounds, but I don't really know what to do with them.

I want to use a single regex to do that if possible, and not use a third-party library, as I have to keep the code as small as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I don't see the similarity between this question and mine. I want to replace something ONLY inside another matched group (the "other group" here being the `<blockquote>`)

Comment: @LGSon The linked question is much more simple: Replace all occurrences of X in a string. In this case the OP wants something that is a step higher in complexity: Replace all occurrences of X that is inside any occurrences of Y. I wouldn't call this a duplicate.

Comment: @Tyler I know...that's why I didn't closed is as a dupe, just posted a comment as a help